# GPG no valid OpenPgp data found while installing docker on Ubuntu 20.04.6

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I want to install docker on my ubuntu on WSL on windows but while I add this command
(from https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/)

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
```

I got error that **GPG no valid OpenPgp data found**...

I use proxy on my laptop. I set .curlrc, .bash_profile and apt.conf files , I'm able to ping for example [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) but I'm not able to get this docker gpg...

Anyone know where can be problem?